# Git merge fails to identify all conflicts correctly

Tags: git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I've had a strange situation where a git merge does not correctly identify all merge conflicts in a file.

If I use `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. to represent blocks of code (which in reality are 100s/1000s of lines of XML), the following happens:

**Original Branched Master File**

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

**Altered File on Feature1 Branch**

```
g
b
c
h
i
d
j
```

**Altered File on Master**

```
a
b
f
d
e
```

So if I merge `master` into `feature1` I **should** get the following conflicted file

```
g
b
<<<<<<< HEAD
c
h
i
=======
f
>>>>>>> master
d
j
```

(and I tested this using files as above, rather than the actual ones, where I do get the correct conflicted file)

But what I actually get with the real files is effectively

```
g
b
c
<<<<<<< HEAD
h
i
=======
f
>>>>>>> master
d
j
```

That is, it thinks blocks `h`/`i` and `f` are in conflict, when actually block `f` is what replaced block `c` in `master`.

Is there any reason why git should mess up like this? I have triple-checked and I'm 99.9% sure that the representation here is accurate.

Comment: Are you also sure there were no merges and/or reverts before? Git really doesn't like reverting merge commits...

Comment: @CptBartender Actually yes there was a reverted commit on master prior to the correct commit. So I was effectively merging 3 commits (original, revert and 'correct' commit). That can cause problems then?

Comment: Reverted commit in and of itself is not a problem - it's only a problem if you revert a merge commit. Example: you have a file in master (comments don't allow newlines in them, so assume spaces are line separators): `a b`. You make a branch and change it to `a c`, then merge it to master. Then on master you make a reverting commit, so it's back to `a b`. Then you change the file on branch to `x c` and merge it to master again. At this point, the branch has `x c` and master has `a b`. From master's perspective, the changes are: `b->c`, `c->b`, `a->x`,  so the merge result is `x b`, not `x c`

Comment: @CptBartender OK thanks, nice clear explanation. So doesn't look like a cause here.